# Why doesn't my page re-access dynamic data in my database?

Tags: c#, php, postgresql

I'm using PHP to connect to Postgres. I wrote a C# application that continually updates a table every 30 seconds.

I put in some test values and set the update time to update every 2 seconds. First, I started the application up and continually refreshed the table in pgAdmin to check if the table itself was updating every 2 seconds. As expected, the table was changing every 2 seconds.

Now that I knew the table was changing. I reset my application and started it over again. I first watched the table change for a couple of rotations in pgAdmin, and then I went to my website to see if the values would change there if I kept refreshing. For some reason, once the values on that page change 1-3 times, they stop changing, even though the C# application is still running and modifying those values. If I go into my text editor, type in a random value, then delete it and save the file, then the same thing will happen where the information on the mainpage will change 1-3 times and then stop.

So I believe resaving a file for my website will allow it to re-access the database. Is there a way to make it so that the page will continually keep changing after a refresh, and not stagnate after 1-3 refreshes?

Comment: is your webserver caching the page? or maybe the DB is caching the query?

Comment: caching would be my bet also

Comment: You guys are right. It was the caching. In this case, I suppose I have to cache per interval. Is it a bad idea to cache every minute?